# How can I ensure a reserved word will not conflict with Ruby, Rails 4, or a gem in my gemlist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, reserved-words

I have a Rails4 application to which I want to add a model named 'Parameters' It's a good choice in terms of the models purpose, but I worry that it is also a common programming term.

What is the best practice (individual steps) to ensure that:

```html
Parameters  
parameter.thing
```

... will not conflict with a reserved word in Ruby, Rails, or my particular Gem list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby has a concept of open classes. That said, when the class `MyClass` is defined somewhere, it’s perfectly valid to have the following in your code:

```
class MyClass
  def another_method
    # do something useful
  end
end
```

That said, there is no “reflection-like” mechanism for this action, since it is how Ruby is intended to work.

One might build the complicated logic like this:

- run the application without new `Parameters` class loaded;
- call `$defined = const_get('Parameters') || true rescue false`;
- use `$defined` global (it’s made global here for the sake of an example) to determine whether the name is free.

or:

- use [`TracePoint#new(:class)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/TracePoint.html#class-TracePoint-label-Example) on `Parameters` to detect whether only yours was loaded.

or

- use [`ObjectSpace#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-each_object) to detect other classes.

or even

- parse sources.

But I would not go with any of solutions above. Just call your class `MyAppParameters` and live with this name.

Comment: Thanks.  This was the sort of insight I was looking for.  I gather these are good approaches to detect which classes are loaded when the check is made.  Doesn't mean that the class in question won't be loaded sometime later, I gather.   I used "ScanParameters", even though it is redundant as the parent class implies "Scan"

Comment: “Doesn't mean that the class in question won't be loaded sometime later”—the approach with `TracePoint` might be used to detect the class loading/reopening at any time of the application’s life. I use it, e. g., when I need to explicitly wait for some class to be loaded to patch it. But here it nevertheless looks like an overkill.

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks again.  I understand this will notify me when a particular class is loaded, but it still seems I cannot foresee or predict that such a case is possible.  I suppose this is a 'cost' of Ruby's open class architecture?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I would not call it “a cost,” though. It’s how things work here :) Anyway, welcome.

Answer (score 1):

An IDE like RubyMine should warn you by coloring the text whenever you use a reserved word, but for people like me who use glorified text editors, you can always check this list of [Rails related reserved words](http://reservedwords.herokuapp.com/) when you're not sure.

Comment: This takes care of Rails and Ruby, but what about the gems?

Comment: @PerryHorwich RubyGems currently lists 7719 gems, so your gem requirement seems both ambitious, and unfortunately, unlikely.

Comment: And... I am really looking for some series of steps that make use of reflection or some other mechanism to ensure I am not going to conflict with a reserved word.  This seems preferable to me as online lists can be out of date.